# Jenkins to deploy on Gitlab merge into development, but ignore updates

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I have Jenkins set up, connected with Gitlab, to do some deployment stuff whenever a merge request gets accepted into the development branch. It pulls the code, runs some incantations, increments the version number, and commits+pushes that new version number in. The only issue, that I just discovered, is that updating old, already merged MRs, even in trivial ways such as updating the milestone or title, will trigger the build. Because of this, when I just updated multiple old merge requests to have the milestone for this release, the version number got incremented ten times or so- not ideal.

My Gitlab triggers inside Jenkins are quite closed down (please note I'm not on EE):

[image: Gitlab triggers in Jenkins]

My Gitlab integrations settings only fire on MR events (and I'm aware there's no way to say only on merging in, rather than editing):

[image: Gitlab integration]

I also have some custom build scripts that do bits and bobs, but the main part that bumps the version number checks that `if [ "$GIT_COMMIT" != "$GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT" ]; then`. However, even though this seemed logical at the time, it became apparent recently that old, stale merge requests will still be true for this when compared to the development HEAD.

There are many different aspects to this that could be the cause of the trouble, and it may be a very easy solution, but I'm not sure what that would be quite yet. Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, I compared the `GIT_COMMIT`, `GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT` and `GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT` values in both the original merge and the later update, and they're all completely different...!

Comment: Secondary question, if I change it to closed merge events, will closing without merging trigger this? Because that is of course also not desired.